# Trace32 doesn't wait until a command gets executed to execute the next command

Tags: trace32

I am running a Practice script inside Trace32. I have noticed that if for example I have this set of commands

```
Go
Step.Over
```

`Step.Over` doesn't necessarily wait for `Go` to finish execution to start. How to tell Trace32 not to execute a command until the other one finished. I have tried inserting `Wait 2.s` after each command. However, since I don't know how long the command will take that doesn't work in every run.

Comment: When has a `Go` command finished completely, in you expectation?

Comment: When I see instead of a loading cursor a normal one and the date.list window view gets updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that with "wait for `Go` to finish execution" you mean to wait until the processor hits a breakpoint. The `Go` command however does not wait until a breakpoint is reached. The execution of the Go command is completed as soon as the processor has been started.

Use the command `WAIT <event> [<timeout>]` to make the script wait for the breakpoint. The timeout is optional, but highly recommended for script robustness.

```
; start execution
Go

;wait until processor halts at breakpoint (timeout: 2 seconds)
WAIT !STATE.RUN() 2s

;error handler
IF STATE.RUN()
(
  PRINT %ERROR "Breakpoint not reached!"
  ENDDO
)

;continue stepping
Step.Over
```